# Can OpenMDAO be installed in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, numpy, openmdao

Is this possible? I know you can have a Python environment in VS.

I have added the Python environment in Visual Studio and OpenMDAO, but they act as different environments, so if I call Numpy (for example) in OpenMDAO, it can't find it, because it's installed in the python2.7 env.

The same thing happens in the Python environment. I can't run OpenMDAO functions because that environment is not active. Any idea how I can use both libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the virtualenv install? if so, maybe this will help? http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/04/pvts-2-0-alpha

The key is to make sure visual studio is looking at the python executable in /bin/python (or the windows equivalent there of!)